# What is light bar component?

Tags: led-driver, led-strip

Have a truck light bar thats not working, one component has rust damage and needs replacing but I don't know what it is.

How do I identify it?

[image: led circuit]

Comment: That's an inductor, 33 microhenries.  I would be wary of assuming that rust = broken = the reason your circuit isn't working however, and of the assumption that simply replacing the part will fix it.  Inductors are made of insulated wire wound around a magnetic core; a bit of surface rust might just be cosmetic.

Comment: Thanks for your information, so, if that component is still functioning, how do I determine the real problem?

Answer (score 2):

The rusty component is a 33 uH inductor.

But uou don't know if the rust has damaged it or not.

If it is damaged, then many other components are also damaged, even if they don't look like it.

If it really is just the inductor and everything else is OK, you don't know anything else from the inductor than the inductance written on it, so it leaves out things like rated current and ESR to be unknown and so not just any 33 uH inductor will work.

Answer (score 1):

That's really rusty. It's a 33 μH power inductor made by someone like Vishay. Maybe check-out their [IHLP range](https://www.vishay.com/en/inductors/ihlp-power-inductors/). Compare the dimensions with one in their vast product range.

[image]

Of course, it could be from Bourns or Coil-craft or Murata etc..